# What is the required compiler to compile sqlalchemy C extensions on Win7 64-bits?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I just updated sqlalchemy and saw the following message:

```
building 'sqlalchemy.cprocessors' extension
***************************************************************************
Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
WARNING: The C extension could not be compiled, speedups are not enabled.
Failure information, if any, is above.
Retrying the build without the C extension now.
***************************************************************************
```

I run Python 3.3 64-bits on Windows 7 64-bits (WinPython distribution).

I would like to compile the C extensions, but what are the options of compilers for Python 64-bits (MinGW, Visual C++ 2010, etc)?

In particular, is it possible to to use Microsoft's Express compilers in lieu of the Professional version?

Finally, if possible, can you also please explain what are the dis/advantages of using a specific compiler?

Thanks!

**Update 1:**

I installed the Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7.1, which in itself was a pain because it does not install if newer versions of redistributables are found.

I followed cgohlke's instructions and it worked, but with the following warnings. Are they normal/expected?

```
building 'sqlalchemy.cprocessors' extension
processors.c
processors.obj : warning LNK4197: export 'PyInit_cprocessors' specified multiple times; using first specification

building 'sqlalchemy.cresultproxy' extension
resultproxy.c
resultproxy.obj : warning LNK4197: export 'PyInit_cresultproxy' specified multiple times; using first specification

building 'sqlalchemy.cutils' extension
utils.c
utils.obj : warning LNK4197: export 'PyInit_cutils' specified multiple times; using first specification
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the free [Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 4](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279), which contains the same compilers used by the official CPython 3.3 distribution, and run the following commands before the install command:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
call "%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin\SetEnv.Cmd" /Release /x64 /vista
set DISTUTILS_USE_SDK=1
```

Alternatively, use the binaries at http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#sqlalchemy